# run command scope in alloy

Tags: alloy

In alloy consider

sig  Queue{
  link : Queue,
  elem: Int
}

consider that I have some predicate  predicate-1,  How would I define scope when I run predicate-1 for Queue <=1 , int ={-3,-2,0,2}. I have not listed the predicate here

run predicate-1 for 1 Queue, int scope here

don't know what would be the syntax for int scope

Answer (score 4):

The syntax is

```
run predicate1 for 1 Queue, 3 Int
```

The scope for integers is always a bitwidth, so you can't specify that the Int set contains exactly {-3. -2. 0. 2}; you can only specify a bitwidth, and all integers within that bitwidth will be used.  In my example above, the Int set will contain all integers from -4 to 3.

Comment: For further refinement, just add conditions to `predicate1` (or write an aditional predicate, and execute `run {predicate1 and intLimit} for 1 Queue, 3 Int`, using the `util/integer` module, to limit the integers used.