# Alloy 4 Int scope

Tags: alloy

Last year I used alloy and I could set the scope of the Int bitwidth writing, for example,
 "5 Int"
as is indeed suggested by the following answer:
[run command scope in alloy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665629/run-command-scope-in-alloy)

However, I have downloaded Alloy 4.1.1 this year again and if I wrote

```
sig Bar{ a:Int}

run{} for 10 Int
```

I now obtain

```
Syntax error at line 3 column 11:
You can no longer set a scope on Int; the number of Int
atoms is always exactly equal to 2^(integer bitwidth).
```

What is changed? How should I set the bitwidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Alloy 4.1.1 just change `Int` to `int`, and that will work.  In Alloy 4.2 you can use either one, because in 4.2 they are both used to specify the bitwidth.

Comment: Thanks, I manged to discover it my own later on, but It was sooo hard to spot, since I was continuously ignoring the case :(